# Concat html tags inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Im stucked concatenating a string to print it as `html` inside an array loop. It does only print the first `anchor` tag inside a div with class `group`. What should I modify to print the anchors inside the `group div`? Here is the example:

```js
var data = [{
        "id": 1969,
        "first_release_date": 1083542400,
        "name": "Item 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1083542400,
        "name": "Item 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 3"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 4"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 5"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 6"
    },
    {
        "id": 9245,
        "first_release_date": 1292976000,
        "name": "Item 7"
    },
    {
        "id": 9245,
        "first_release_date": 1292976000,
        "name": "Item 8"
    },
    
    {
        "id": 9245,
        "first_release_date": 1566950400,
        "name": "Item 9"
    }
];

var tag = "",
    release = "",
    releaseChecker = 0;

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    if (data[key].first_release_date != releaseChecker) {
        release = new Date(data[key].first_release_date * 1000);
        tag += '<h4>' + release.getDate() + '</h4>';
    }

    if (data[key].first_release_date != releaseChecker) {
        tag += '<div class="group">';
    }

    tag += '<a class="test" href="#">'+data[key].name+'</a>, ';

    if (data[key].first_release_date != releaseChecker) {
        tag += '</div>';
    }
    releaseChecker = data[key].first_release_date;
});
$(".el").html(tag);
```

```css
.group {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el"></div>
```

Comment: You need another inner loop to create the `a` elements. However, I don't see how this code matches the output you say you're getting, as it only ever produces one `a` wrapped in a `div` per iteration.

Comment: Also should provide  sample of the data so we can reproduce the problem. Click on `<>` in question editor to make this into a runnable snippet

Comment: Also, if you really want line breaks and indentation in the output, you're going to need changes like `'...</h4>\n'` and `tag += '  <a...'`.

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated the code with a snippet example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a problem at closing div point,

```
if (data[key].first_release_date != releaseChecker) {
        tag += '</div>';
    }
```

This executes on the first iteration, To prevent this add a zero check

```
if (releaseChecker != 0 && data[key].first_release_date != releaseChecker) {
        tag += '</div>';
    }
```

and you need to move it to start of loop to stop including next heading in the div

```js
var data = [{
        "id": 1969,
        "first_release_date": 1083542400,
        "name": "Item 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1083542400,
        "name": "Item 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 3"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 4"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 5"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 6"
    },
    {
        "id": 9245,
        "first_release_date": 1292976000,
        "name": "Item 7"
    },
    {
        "id": 9245,
        "first_release_date": 1292976000,
        "name": "Item 8"
    },
    
    {
        "id": 9245,
        "first_release_date": 1566950400,
        "name": "Item 9"
    }
];

var tag = "",
    release = "",
    releaseChecker = 0;

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    if (releaseChecker != 0 && data[key].first_release_date != releaseChecker) {
        tag += '</div>';
    }
    if (data[key].first_release_date != releaseChecker) {
        release = new Date(data[key].first_release_date * 1000);
        tag += '<h4>' + release.getDate() + '</h4>';
        tag += '<div class="group">';
    }

    tag += '<a class="test" href="#">'+data[key].name+'</a>, ';

    releaseChecker = data[key].first_release_date;
});
$(".el").html(tag);
```

```css
.group {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el"></div>
```

Comment: While the code may solve issue , always provide an explanation of what was chnged and why so people don't have to search for differences

Comment: Isn't `Object.keys()` to be used with `Object`?

Comment: arrays are considered objects in JavaScript so I thinks it's fine to use Object.keys() with array which will return array of indexes

Comment: You're right but isn't it redundant to get keys and then access with it instead of just use `forEach` and get the value? The problem has nothing with the indexes, I think.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys()` is used for `object` but the `data` is array here. It may work **but** it can cause some unexpected behavior.

Instead of using `Object.keys()`, first you can create another array that holds **grouped** data and then iterate over it.

Here's a working snippet:

UPDATE NOTE: Instead of hardcoding `,` at the end, you can use `map` and `join` in order to add commas.

```js
var data = [{
        "id": 1969,
        "first_release_date": 1083542400,
        "name": "Item 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1083542400,
        "name": "Item 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 3"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 4"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 5"
    },
    {
        "id": 25076,
        "first_release_date": 1540512000,
        "name": "Item 6"
    },
    {
        "id": 9245,
        "first_release_date": 1292976000,
        "name": "Item 7"
    },
    {
        "id": 9245,
        "first_release_date": 1292976000,
        "name": "Item 8"
    },
    
    {
        "id": 9245,
        "first_release_date": 1566950400,
        "name": "Item 9"
    }
];


    var tag = "",
    release = "",
    releaseChecker = 0,
    groupedData = [];

   data.forEach(function(item) {
        release = new Date(item.first_release_date * 1000);
        if(!groupedData.find(d => d.releaseDate === release.getDate())){
           groupedData.push({releaseDate: release.getDate(), items: []});
        }
        
        groupedData.find(d => d.releaseDate === release.getDate()).items.push(item);
       
    
  });
 groupedData.forEach(function(data){
 
    tag += '<h4>' + data.releaseDate + '</h4>';
    tag += '<div class="group">';
    
    tag += data.items.map(function(item){
       return '<a class="test" href="#">'+item.name+'</a>';
    }).join(', ');
    
    tag += '</div>';
 
 });
 
 $(".el").html(tag);
```

```css
.group {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var tag = "",
    release = "",
    releaseChecker = 0, 
    linkGroup = '';
var linkContainer = '';


Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {

    if (data[key].first_release_date != releaseChecker) {
        release = new Date(data[key].first_release_date * 1000);
        tag += '<h4>' + release.getDate() + '</h4>';
        linkContainer = '<div class="group">#linkGroup</div>';
    }


    linkGroup += '<a class="test" href="#">'+data[key].name+'</a>, ';

    if (data[key].first_release_date != releaseChecker) {
        tag += linkContainer.replace(/\#linkGroup/g, linkGroup);
    }


    releaseChecker = data[key].first_release_date;
});
$(".el").html(tag);
```

**DEMO**
https://jsbin.com/coduvobaqi/edit?html,js,output